# Why the APK size is different from what is described on Google Play?

Tags: android, apk

E.g. The game [Virtual City Playground](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.g5e.virtualcitysb) has 180MB as described on Google Play.

When I downloaded it, it did take the time for downloading such a big file.

However, when I look into the APK

`/data/app/com.g5e.virtualcitysb-1.apk`

Its size is just 7MB.

Where does the remaining parts (180MB-7MB) go?

FYI: My android version is 4.2.

Comment: The Play Store might count [APK expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) as part of its total or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot! That is a nice link, which explains the basic reason. However, I still could not find the *.obb for this virtual city game. I did observe GameSoft's obb files located in /sdcard/Android/data/..